# How to get the URL of an ics file from a webpage containing a calendar?

Tags: python

For example, I have the following web page containing a calendar:

https://meded.hms.harvard.edu/calendar

Below is my code attempt to download the ics:

```
import urllib2

url = 'https://meded.hms.harvard.edu/calendar'

response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
webContent = response.read()

f = open('calendar.ics', 'w')
f.write(webContent)
f.close
```

However, because I did not specify the specific URL of the .ics file, it obviously downloads a file with nothing in it so I can't open it with something like iCal. My question is, how can I get the specific URL of the .ics file so I can download it? I tried searching for how to download a specific file on stack overflow already but all the answers had URLs containing the file, so I did not know what to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach gave me a file that seems to work on my mailer which is Mozilla Thunderbird.

```
>>> import requests
>>> page = requests.get('https://meded.hms.harvard.edu/calendar').content
>>> import bs4
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
>>> link = soup.find('a', attrs={'class': 'subscribe'})
>>> link
<a class="subscribe" href="https://meded.hms.harvard.edu/calendar/upcoming/all/export.ics">subscribe</a>
>>> link.attrs['href']
'https://meded.hms.harvard.edu/calendar/upcoming/all/export.ics'
>>> ics = requests.get(link.attrs['href']).content
>>> open('med_school.ics', 'wb').write(ics)
1699
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: However, how can I generalize this code to work for all urls like this? I got an error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack3.py", line 96, in <module>
    get_ics_url('https://careers.unc.edu/calendar')
  File "stack3.py", line 28, in get_ics_url
    print link.attrs['href']
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrs'

Comment: On StackOverflow when you receive an answer that does what you want you should, please, mark it accepted. This raises your reputation as well as that of the person that provided the answer.

Comment: Making code to work for *all* such pages would be fairly high art for most programmers, I'm afraid. There are simply too many possible variations that would have to be taken into account. In the specific case you've mentioned, however, it appears that just one line would require replacing: `link = soup.find('a', attrs={'class': 'ical-icon'})`. **This would be unusual** IMO.

Comment: Sure thing, sorry I appreciate your help. Just upvoted/accepted your answer (unfortunately I do not have 15 reputation yet). As for getting the specific URL of a page containing an ics calendar, if this is not realistically feasible to program it to work for all such pages, how exactly does one acquire the URL manually one by one, or is this the only method? Basically I need to download from the ics URL and then save it as an .ics file as before.

Comment: Having since been for a walk with my dog it now occurs to me that you could use scrapy. You seem interested only in American universities, you could insist that scrapy check only those sites for links. Since there are so many of them you could consider trying to limit the number somehow. Ask scrapy to look for links and, as it does so, to report the ones that point to .ics files. Unless you can limit the number of sites you check, you seem likely to get an *enormous* number of .ics files. Don't worry about the voting, etc. I just wanted you to know about the site etiquette.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Will definitely check out scrapy.